# How to make a report execute only when the difference between two date/time parameter is less than 2 hours

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, datediff

My SSRS report has a Start parameter and a End parameter.  When I make a dataset dependent on a stored procedure, the parameters and fields are imported.  In the stored procedure the Start and End parameters are date/time fields but when the dataset is created, SSRS labels them as text fields.

I want the report to only execute when the difference between start and end are 2 or less.

I've tried creating Ustart and Uend parameters that convert the text fields to date/time fields cDate(Parameters!Start.Value) then I create a 3rd parameter @TIMESPAN and make the default DATEDIFF("n",Parameters!Ustart.Value,Parameters!Uend.Value) but the result is always zero.

It appears the problem is in the Ustart parameter not updating when the user changes the default date.

Is there an easier way to do this?

MK

Comment: why not just add another where clause to your stored procedure.. something like and datediff(minute,@Ustart,@Uend)>=2..

Comment: So basically what Harry is saying is that you have an outer SP that can capture all the user params and pass them to an inner SP. But before you execute you check the difference between dates for >= 2 (be days, hrs, mins, etc). Let us know if you need help with syntax. This technique can also be applied if report has bunch of params and you wish to run a combo of those params. Helps with execution plans.

Comment: Great! Thank you!